# Simplify multiple ReadProcessMemory calls

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, process, reverse-engineering

I started experimenting a bit with Cheat Engine lately to be able to read data from the memory of a running process and stumbled upon step 8 of the tutorial. There is a particular value I want to read from my application stored at `[[[[[0x00645390]+0xC]+0x14]+0x0]+0x18]` of the second process I am reading from with `0x00645390` being static.

Currently it works with the following snippet of insane pointer handling:

```
::ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (void *)0x00645390,           (void *)&dwAddress, sizeof(dwAddress), NULL);
::ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (void *)(dwAddress + 0xc),    (void *)&dwAddress, sizeof(dwAddress), NULL);
::ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (void *)(dwAddress + 0x14),   (void *)&dwAddress, sizeof(dwAddress), NULL);
::ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (void *)(dwAddress),          (void *)&dwAddress, sizeof(dwAddress), NULL);
::ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (void *)(dwAddress + 0x18),   (void *)&dwValue,   sizeof(dwAddress), NULL);
```

I was wondering if there is a function or a shorter notation I can use when I have both the base adress and some offsets at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could of course have a static array with:

```
int offset[] = { 0, 12, 20, 0, 24 };/* (or 0xC, 0x14,m 0, 0x18) */

dwAddress = 0x00645390;
for( auto i : offset)
    ::ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (void *)(dwAddress + i),
                        (void *)&dwAddress, sizeof(dwAddress), NULL);
dwValue = dwAddress;
```

Not sure it gains much.

What you are doing is basically following a set of pointers, so:

```
 global->something->other->thingy->value
```

You need to read each pointer at each level, so there is no shortcut from reading all the addresses. [This applies also when the compiler has to access a long chain of pointers - each pointer has to be read before the element that the pointer points at can be accessed]

(Not sure I got enough elements in there, but the concept applies)